# Converting VBA to SQL - Datediff issue

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to figure out how MS access calculates the following query where contractualDate and ContractualTime are both datetime:

```
(Max(([contractualDate]+[ContractualTime]))-Min(([contractualDate]+[ContractualTime])))*25,0) AS TrailerCost
```

The closest I could think of using SQL is

```
Datediff(m,Min(([contractualDate]+[ContractualTime])),Max(([contractualDate]+[ContractualTime])))*25 AS TrailerCost
```

This gives me results that differ from the first VBA code, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Differs how? ... can you append to the question the output differences between the two, as well as the values for the two contract date and time values.

Comment: Default unit for arithmetic with date/time is DAY. The second expression specifies whatever `m` is. Is this a field name? If not, the expression should error. DateDiff unit parameter should be a string within quote marks unless is it input by a variable - `DateDiff("m", ...)`. If you don't use quote marks, Access will likely throw `[ ]` around it. So your posted expression isn't making sense.

Comment: Okay, apparently SQL in SQLServer does not require the unit parameter to be within quote marks. So are you building query in Access or SQLServer?